# as3 draw smoother round corners

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, draw

I use the following script to draw:

```
private function drawBkg():void {
    _bkg_shp.graphics.clear();
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0, 1, false, LineScaleMode.NORMAL, CapsStyle.ROUND, JointStyle.ROUND);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.moveTo(_round, 0);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(_width - _round, 0);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.curveTo(_width, 0, _width, _round);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(_width, _height - _round);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.curveTo(_width, _height, _width - _round, _height);

    // draw down arrow
    const startPont:int = (_width + _arrowBase) * 0.5;

    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(startPont, _height);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(int(_width * 0.5), _height + _arrowHeight);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(int(startPont - _arrowBase), _height);

    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(_round, _height);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.curveTo(0, _height, 0, _height -_round);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.lineTo(0, _round);
    _bkg_shp.graphics.curveTo(0, 0, _round, 0);
}
```

And the result is:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/9bgcHV7sMW]

Do anyone know how to remove the fuzziness of the of the rounds? Snapping to the pixel, depends on the sizes can improve or worsen the shape.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the thickness of the line stroke weight will help:

[image: callout]

```
import flash.display.CapsStyle;
import flash.display.JointStyle;
import flash.display.LineScaleMode;

graphics.lineStyle(2,
                   0x0,
                   1.0,
                   true,
                   LineScaleMode.NORMAL,
                   CapsStyle.SQUARE,
                   JointStyle.MITER);
```

Answer (score -1):

The common solution to avoid that problem with lines is just not to use them :)

You can draw round rectangles only by fills:
For example that code draws one:

```
/**
 * Draw rectangle with rounded corners with fills (without lines) for 
 * nice scaling of corners
 */
public static function drawRoundRectAsFill (graphics:Graphics, 
                                            x:Number, y:Number, 
                                            w:Number, h:Number, 
                                            radius:Number,
                                            lineColor:uint=0x000000, fillColor:uint=0xffffff,
                                            lineThickness:Number=1,
                                            lineAlpha:Number=1, fillAlpha:Number=1):void
{
    graphics.lineStyle(0,0,0);
    graphics.beginFill(lineColor, lineAlpha);
    graphics.drawRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    graphics.drawRoundRect(x+lineThickness, y+lineThickness, w-2*lineThickness, h-2*lineThickness, 2*radius-2*lineThickness, 2*radius-2*lineThickness);
    graphics.endFill();

    graphics.beginFill(fillColor,fillAlpha);
    graphics.drawRoundRect(x+lineThickness, y+lineThickness, w-2*lineThickness, h-2*lineThickness, 2*radius-2*lineThickness, 2*radius-2*lineThickness);
    graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but only using drawRoundRect you cannot do the shape that I posted and fill it after with gradient.

Comment: the code for arrow should be the same as you have (or you can draw it only with fills if you want to have smooth scaling here as well). You didn't say about gradient. In that case I think the best solution will be draw it in Flash IDE (again only with fills, without lines)

Answer (score -2):

Use shapes for everything.  Don't use lines.  Ever.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I need to back this up?  Lines look horrible.  This is a fact, not an opinion.  Lines are totally inferior and inefficent.  I'm a designer/programmer and have been doing Flash professionally over a decade.  I've never used lines.

Comment: Also, the question is "remove the fuzziness..."  You can not "remove the fuzziness" of lines.  You can only hide the fuzziness.  The answer is:  use shapes.